# Want to filter for the max result and print from a table that contains many results for multiple scenarios

Tags: perl

I have a CSV table where I have the merged data for **1024 independent variables** and **25 dependent variables** that are associated with them. For each independent variable (called 1 .. 1024), I have 10 different outcomes. I would like to

1. choose the best result for each independent variable, and
2. pipe the line containing that information into a new CSV file.

It seems like a fairly easy thing to ask of perl, and maybe it would be simple to do with a hash of an array of an array, but I'm still confused about how I could implement something like that for this collection of data.

#### Current code

I found a [very helpful Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523846/how-can-i-print-a-matching-line-one-line-immediately-above-it-and-one-line-imme) from 2009 on printing matching lines. It works fairly well after some tinkering, but a few issues remain:

- I have to pre-sort the file so that my maximum value is the first value that appears for each case.
- I also miss out on getting the best result for the first independent variable and
- in some instances I get multiple lines returned to me instead of just the maximum value.

I'm fairly sure there must be an easier way to do this, and I would greatly appreciate any help and/or constructive criticism on my (ripped-off) script.

Thank  you!

This is what I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use warnings;
use strict;
unless ($#ARGV == 0) {
  print "USAGE:  get_best.pl  csvfile \n";
  exit;
}
### this is a script to get the best "score"
my $input = $ARGV[0];
my $outfile = "bestofthebest.csv";
if (-e $outfile ) {    
  system "rm $outfile";
}
open(my $fh,'<',"$input") || die "could not open $input"; #try to open input
open (SUMMARY, ">>","$outfile") || die "could not open $outfile"; #open output file for writing
my $this_line = "";
my $do_next = 0;

while (<$fh>) {
  chomp($_);
  my $last_line = $this_line;
  $this_line = $_;
  if ($this_line =~ m/Seq/) {
    print SUMMARY "$this_line\n";next;
  }
  my ($compound,     $rank,     $nnme,     $G1,     ..., $res1,     $res2,     $res3,     $res4,     $res5,     $res6    ) = split(/\s+/, $this_line, 26);
  my ($compound_old, $rank_old, $nnme_old, $G1_old, ..., $res1_old, $res2_old, $res3_old, $res4_old, $res5_old, $res6_old) = split(/\s+/, $last_line, 26);
  foreach ($compound == $compound_old) {
    if (($G1 >= $G1_old)){
      print SUMMARY "$this_line\n";
      print "\n $G1 G1 is >> $G1_old G1_old loop\n";
      print "\n compound is $compound G1 is $G1\n";
      $do_next = 1;
    }
    else {
      $last_line = "";
      $do_next = 0;
    } 
  }
}
close ($fh);
close (SUMMARY);
```

#### Example input

This is what the input data looks like (I've left off some columns and rows, obviously)

```
10  8   3   -18.08  -1.4    -16.68  -15.94  -2.13   -9.45
11  10  4   -15.2   3.2 -18.4   -18.02  2.82    -5
11  5   4   -15.22  2.71    -17.92  -15.88  0.66    -4.51
11  7   4   -14.06  3.84    -17.89  -16.7   2.64    -5.73
11  4   4   -16.63  0.48    -17.1   -15.75  -0.87   -5.92
11  6   4   -15.21  1.83    -17.04  -18.41  3.21    -7
11  9   4   -15.18  1.82    -17 -16.56  1.38    -7.09
11  8   4   -14.98  1.93    -16.91  -16.78  1.79    -10.81
11  2   4   -18.75  -1.95   -16.8   -17.83  -0.92   -7.35
11  1   4   -19.67  -3.17   -16.5   -16.4   -3.27   -9.01
11  3   4   -16.69  -0.54   -16.14  -16.35  -0.34   -9.17
12  7   4   -19.54  -1.14   -18.41  -17.74  -1.81   -2.79
12  9   4   -19.09  -1.01   -18.08  -16.01  -3.09   -5.56
12  4   4   -19.48  -2.18   -17.3   -16.34  -3.14   -4
12  2   4   -19.86  -2.77   -17.1   -15.97  -3.9    -2.96
12  8   4   -19.49  -2.45   -17.03  -16.39  -3.1    -7.19
12  1   4   -20.28  -3.33   -16.95  -17.12  -3.16   -5.18
12  3   4   -18.78  -1.93   -16.86  -17.81  -0.98   -5.39
12  5   4   -19.63  -2.86   -16.77  -16.41  -3.22   -6.54
12  6   4   -19.81  -3.25   -16.56  -16.53  -3.27   -7.19
12  10  4   -19.39  -2.95   -16.44  -17.42  -1.97   -7.67
13  1   3   -13.05  6.35    -19.4   -18.71  5.66    -6.43
13  8   3   -21.44  -2.32   -19.11  -17.08  -4.36   -1.93
13  3   3   -16 2.94    -18.94  -19.24  3.24    -2.78
13  2   3   -13.79  4.9 -18.7   -17.35  3.56    -4.72
13  6   3   -22.08  -3.4    -18.68  -20.12  -1.96   -6.74
13  9   3   -18.98  -0.32   -18.66  -15.97  -3.01   -3.06
13  7   3   -20.4   -2.08   -18.32  -18.24  -2.17   -5.71
13  5   3   -19.94  -1.62   -18.32  -19.42  -0.52   -7.44
13  10  3   -19.26  -1.25   -18.01  -17.52  -1.74   -5.68
13  4   3   -17.75  -1.33   -16.42  -17.75  0   -9.15
14  9   3   -22.23  -3.43   -18.79  -16.68  -5.55   -3.91
14  5   3   -21.32  -2.95   -18.37  -18.08  -3.24   -6.03
14  7   3   -24.25  -6.29   -17.96  -18.78  -5.47   -9.21
14  6   3   -21.03  -3.14   -17.89  -19.17  -1.86   -10.11
14  4   3   -21.59  -3.93   -17.67  -19.32  -2.28   -6.55
14  1   3   -22.43  -4.79   -17.63  -18.09  -4.34   -5.63
```

#### Current Output:

```
10  2   3   -10.11  8.94    -19.04  -18.48  8.38    -4.09
11  5   4   -15.22  2.71    -17.92  -15.88  0.66    -4.51
12  7   4   -19.54  -1.14   -18.41  -17.74  -1.81   -2.79
12  6   4   -19.81  -3.25   -16.56  -16.53  -3.27   -7.19
13  8   3   -21.44  -2.32   -19.11  -17.08  -4.36   -1.93
14  9   3   -22.23  -3.43   -18.79  -16.68  -5.55   -3.91
15  10  4   -21.51  -1.51   -20 -17.63  -3.88   -2.45
16  5   4   -17.81  2.56    -20.37  -19.09  1.28    -1.19
16  2   4   -16.61  1.97    -18.58  -21.06  4.45    -6.47
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the follow will be helpful:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash;

while (<DATA>) {
    my ( $indVarID, $val ) = (split)[ 0, 3 ];

    $hash{$indVarID} = [ $val, $_ ]
      if !exists $hash{$indVarID}
      or $hash{$indVarID}[0] < $val;
}

print $hash{$_}[1] for sort { $a <=> $b } keys %hash;

__DATA__
11  7   4   -14.06  3.84    -17.89  -16.7   2.64    -5.73
11  4   4   -16.63  0.48    -17.1   -15.75  -0.87   -5.92
11  6   4   -15.21  1.83    -17.04  -18.41  3.21    -7
11  9   4   -15.18  1.82    -17 -16.56  1.38    -7.09
11  8   4   -14.98  1.93    -16.91  -16.78  1.79    -10.81
11  2   4   -18.75  -1.95   -16.8   -17.83  -0.92   -7.35
11  1   4   -19.67  -3.17   -16.5   -16.4   -3.27   -9.01
11  3   4   -16.69  -0.54   -16.14  -16.35  -0.34   -9.17
12  7   4   -19.54  -1.14   -18.41  -17.74  -1.81   -2.79
12  9   4   -19.09  -1.01   -18.08  -16.01  -3.09   -5.56
12  4   4   -19.48  -2.18   -17.3   -16.34  -3.14   -4
12  2   4   -19.86  -2.77   -17.1   -15.97  -3.9    -2.96
12  8   4   -19.49  -2.45   -17.03  -16.39  -3.1    -7.19
12  1   4   -20.28  -3.33   -16.95  -17.12  -3.16   -5.18
12  3   4   -18.78  -1.93   -16.86  -17.81  -0.98   -5.39
12  5   4   -19.63  -2.86   -16.77  -16.41  -3.22   -6.54
12  6   4   -19.81  -3.25   -16.56  -16.53  -3.27   -7.19
12  10  4   -19.39  -2.95   -16.44  -17.42  -1.97   -7.67
13  1   3   -13.05  6.35    -19.4   -18.71  5.66    -6.43
13  8   3   -21.44  -2.32   -19.11  -17.08  -4.36   -1.93
13  3   3   -16 2.94    -18.94  -19.24  3.24    -2.78
13  2   3   -13.79  4.9 -18.7   -17.35  3.56    -4.72
13  6   3   -22.08  -3.4    -18.68  -20.12  -1.96   -6.74
13  9   3   -18.98  -0.32   -18.66  -15.97  -3.01   -3.06
13  7   3   -20.4   -2.08   -18.32  -18.24  -2.17   -5.71
13  5   3   -19.94  -1.62   -18.32  -19.42  -0.52   -7.44
13  10  3   -19.26  -1.25   -18.01  -17.52  -1.74   -5.68
13  4   3   -17.75  -1.33   -16.42  -17.75  0   -9.15
14  9   3   -22.23  -3.43   -18.79  -16.68  -5.55   -3.91
14  5   3   -21.32  -2.95   -18.37  -18.08  -3.24   -6.03
14  7   3   -24.25  -6.29   -17.96  -18.78  -5.47   -9.21
14  6   3   -21.03  -3.14   -17.89  -19.17  -1.86   -10.11
14  4   3   -21.59  -3.93   -17.67  -19.32  -2.28   -6.55
14  1   3   -22.43  -4.79   -17.63  -18.09  -4.34   -5.63
```

Output:

```
11  7   4   -14.06  3.84    -17.89  -16.7   2.64    -5.73
12  3   4   -18.78  -1.93   -16.86  -17.81  -0.98   -5.39
13  1   3   -13.05  6.35    -19.4   -18.71  5.66    -6.43
14  6   3   -21.03  -3.14   -17.89  -19.17  -1.86   -10.11
```

This builds a hash of arrays (HoA), where the key is the independent variable ID and the value is a reference to a two-element list.  The zeroth element in the list is the value found in the record's fourth column.  The first element is the record.

As records are being read, if a new value for an independent variable is greater than the older value (or if there wasn't an older one), the new value and record are stored in the list.

When done, the keys are numerically sorted and the records which contained the greatest value for each independent variable ID are printed.

Comment: It is absolutely helpful! It works, it's shorter, and a perfect way to learn more properly using hashes -- Thank you very much!